# Android copy existing databse into local sqllite db

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm copying an existing database from assets folder into the device local db. The db file is test.sql and this is the copy databases code:

```
 private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open("test.sql");

    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    Log.i(TAG, outFileName);
    byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int mLength;
    while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer)) > 0) {
        mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
    }
    mOutput.flush();
    mOutput.close();
    mInput.close();
}
```

Database is created successfully, but the tables are not copied. Here is the contents of the test.sql file:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test1` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `namenew` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;


INSERT INTO `test1` (`id`, `namenew`) VALUES
(1, 'fgfg'),
(2, 'fgf');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test2` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `testname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Cant you just use the `OnCreate` method in `DBHelper` class, and run those 3 queries?

Comment: actually its a sample, i need to import a large db :)

Comment: You have an InnoDB engine, I'm guessing there is a possibility that a check failed and so the values were not inserted. Have you viewed the `test.sql` file to confirm the queries are there and then have you directly tested a query with your database admin tool to see if the query actually works or fails?

Comment: How big is your sql?WHich OS version are you running this sample?

Comment: Did I get that right, you copy a file with SQL statements in it and want to use it as an SQLite database?

Comment: Right henry. I want to do that.

Comment: I'm using sdk 7 and higher. Weird case is that im using sqlitestudio-2.1.4.exe to create the database and export sql file from there. When i want to import same database file into that, no tables were imported.

Comment: @user2534310 You need to copy the database file and not the SQL statements.

Comment: So that must a .db file i guess. Also do i need to specify test.db in InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open("test.db") ?

Comment: Yes, it must be the name of the database file.